# Хук beforeRouteUpdate для каждого router-link, vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Есть список вопросов, который хранится в складе Vuex. Также в складе хранится номер выбранного вопроса, отображаемого во Vue. url отображает выбранный вопрос с помощью Vue-Router. По клику на кнопку происходит переход к следующему вопросу. В хуке  beforeRouteUpdate на уровне компонента в склад пробрасывается изменение отображаемого вопроса. Все работает. Но хочется добавить переход к предыдущему вопросу. Тут возникают трудности. Выношу router-link в отдельный компонент - QuestionButton.vue, но хук тут уже не работает. Не понимаю, как сделать для каждого router-link отдельный рабочий хук.

TestQuestion.vue

```
    <template>
        <section>
            <h1>Вопрос</h1>
            <ul>
                <question-button
                        v-bind:id="id"
                        v-bind:questionNumber="questionNumber-1"
                        v-bind:value="'Предыдущий вопрос'">
                </question-button>
                <question-button
                        v-bind:id="id"
                        v-bind:questionNumber="questionNumber+1"
                        v-bind:value="'Следующий вопрос'">
                </question-button>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </template>

export default {
        components: {
            'QuestionButton': QuestionButton
        }
        //Тут beforeRouteUpdate срабатывает. Но пробрасывать изменения в склад здесь не получится, 
        //т.к. для каждой кнопки необходимо пробрасывать свое значение.
    }
```

QuestionButton.vue

```
<template>
    <section>
        <router-link :to="{
                        name: 'testing',
                        path: 'testing',
                        params: {
                            id: id,
                            questionNumber: questionNumber
                        }
                     }"
                     tag="li">
            <input type="button" v-bind:value="value"/>
        </router-link>
    </section>
</template>

export default {
        props: ['id', 'questionNumber', 'value'],
        beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
            //Не работает
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем отслеживать изменения роутера в компоненте. Компонент это Вью. Роутер это контроллер.

Как обычно делают.

Всю логику роутера выносят в файл - например в файл `/router/index.js`

В компонентах используют или router-link или прямо пушат роутеру маршруты `this.$router.push('...')
 this.$router.push({ name: '...', params: { ... } })`

В роутере обрабатывают события

По описанию не понятно зачем так всё усложнять. Представим что вопрос отображается по опрделённому URL. Просто заводим в стор объект "текущий вопрос". Заводим коневой элемент компонент "вьюшку". Все компоненты по отношению к вьюшке дочерние. Только вьюшка может менять "текущий вопрос". Все больше ничего делать не нужно.  Компонеты всегда обращаются в стор к текушему вопросу. Компонент кнопка пушит новый маршрут роутеру. Роутер кидает вьюшке параметры. Вьюшка меняет в зависимости от параметров "текущий вопрос" в сторе. "Текуший вопрос" реактивно связан с маршрутом в роутере, с компонентами которые его отображают. Никакие хуки не нужны.